# How to acquire API key for Airbnb

Tags: api, api-key

I know that Airbnb haven't opened their API to the public yet, but searching the internet I found some people are using it.

I tried to contact them, and also Airbnb, but without any answers.

Does anyone here knows any contact email, page, or phone number that I can refer to?

Answer (score 11):

I have read [here](https://packagist.org/packages/jonnyd/airbnbsdk) that you can find your API key by looking at the requests that AirBNB uses in their own website. So use the web-developer tools in chrome, or firefox, or firebug in firefox and search trough the requests in the network panel until you find the key being used in any JSON request. Some urls contain this key param, you copy that :) works for me!

Oh BTW, i'd like to remind you that the API is currently not officially released to fetch data in the background while you are logged in. When you use this key, they'll know your identity. You might get blocked or at least warned by AirBNB for using their API while you are maybe not allowed to. Read their terms & conditions to make sure. I am not taking any responsibility, of course ;)

Comment: You'll need the clientid which is seen as key parameter if you use fiddler to look at the requests and response. Also, you'll need the userid. I think I found ours in the session string.

Answer (score 6):

You can now find your API key on the meta tags of the source code when logged in to your dashboard. Search for canonical_host and you will find:

```
{"canonical_host":"www.airbnb.com","api_config":{"key":"<your-api-key>"}
```

Comment: Actually you don't even need to be logged and the api_key that you find is not an api_key that authenticates your own account but a generic one.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update this set of answers, the api is on the following address but you need to request access first.

https://www.airbnb.com/partner

It offers an FAQ that informs you about the process and it will always be updated

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, they have shut down this service as of today.
"Unfortunately, this is no longer available" will be what the API returns.

EDIT:
It started working again after a few days. Very odd, maybe an internal problem, or we were rate limited or something.

Answer (score 0):

Log into Airbnb.com, open up the web developer console, go to the network tab, filter by type json, and look at the url and find "client_id".
I found this answer [here](https://packagist.org/packages/jonnyd/airbnbsdk)