# Airbnb API key not unique per user

Tags: api, key, unique

I have been researching the Airbnb API and have started working with it and making some requests. Some API calls such as calendar_months require an API key:
https://www.airbnb.com/api/v2/calendar_months?key=your_api_key&listing_id=17794278&_format=with_price

I know that your API key can be found in the meta tags, or by inspecting requests in the browser ([How to acquire API key for Airbnb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243819/how-to-acquire-api-key-for-airbnb)). This is fine, and I've successfully located my API key.

My concern is that this key does not appear to be unique. I've retrieved the API key from multiple computers on multiple networks with separate IP addresses -- even from a server in another country with no association to my previous Airbnb activity. I always find the same API key: d306zoyjsyarp7ifhu67rjxn52tv0t20

I'd normally never post the key for my account somewhere (obviously), but it's clear that this API key is not unique to me. A quick google search shows that many people are already using it:
https://www.google.com/search?q=d306zoyjsyarp7ifhu67rjxn52tv0t20

You can find the same situation with API key 3092nxybyb0otqw18e8nh5nty. This one I initially found in the old unofficial airbnb api docs ([Does you have a copy of a documentation of unofficial AirBnb API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44107282/does-you-have-a-copy-of-a-documentation-of-unofficial-airbnb-api)) so it's understandable that some people might have found it there and started using it.

I've searched extensively to find some discussion on this, but I can't find anything and I have a number of questions about this:

- Look up your own API key and do a google search for it -- is anyone else sharing your key?
- Do you receive different keys on separate computers / networks?
- Why would Airbnb require a key for certain requests, if the key does not to uniquely identify the user?
- Is there something I'm overlooking which would allow them to identify me even though many people are sharing this key?
- How can I acquire a truly unique API key?
- Why is no one talking about this?

Thanks!

Comment: It's the key for the "unique" user `Airbnb Tech Team` :p. They don't want to open a public API but they don't seem to mind if people use their private API

Comment: These were/are questions for Airbnb support to answer, not questions about programming as defined by the [help].

Answer (score 4):

I have check my airbnb API Key again, it is the same with yours: `d306zoyjsyarp7ifhu67rjxn52tv0t20`

Just Before I looked this question, I thought this key is **unique** to my account.

> Look up your own API key and do a google search for it -- is anyone else sharing your key?

**No one is sharing your airbnb key, and everyone is sharing this key.**

> Do you receive different keys on separate computers / networks?

**No. I have checked in different computers/networks**

> Why would Airbnb require a key for certain requests, if the key does not to uniquely identify the user?

**I have found that Airbnb use IP address to identify different user.**

> Is there something I'm overlooking which would allow them to identify me even though many people are sharing this key?

**I guess there are another parameters help airbnb to identify different users. But I didn't find yet.**

> How can I acquire a truly unique API key?

**Don't Know. Only the Airbnb Engineering Team knows.**

> Why is no one talking about this?

**I thinks everyone will think this key is unique to him/her.**